# Adversarial examples in mixture density networks?

Tags: neural-networks, references, definition

Mixture density networks (MDNs), [first introduced by Christopher Bishop in 1994](https://publications.aston.ac.uk/id/eprint/373/1/NCRG_94_004.pdf), are a type of neural network that output a probability distribution over categories.

I am wondering what an [adversarial example](https://christophm.github.io/interpretable-ml-book/adversarial.html) would look like in an MDN. Usually an adversarial example causes the network to output the wrong class (for a small change in the input feature vector). How would an adversarial example be defined for an MDN? Has anyone seen such a definition in the literature?